# Eclipse SVN Change History in Java Editor

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

Is there a way to see the changes in the Java editor in the annotations bar (next to the scrollbar) which normally highlights errors,warnings,todos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See my blog post on how to activate the feature: http://blog.firdau.si/2010/07/09/eclipse-quick-diff-see-what-changes-youve-made-since-last-checkout/

Quote:

> This feature is called Quick Diff. It is turned on as default but the reference source is the last saved version. If your project use SVN (or CVS, Mercurial, Git as long as you use the Eclipse plugin for that SCM), you can change the Quick Diff behavior to compare the code on your machine with the latest code in the SCM.
>
> Go to Preferences and select General → Editors → Text Editors → Quick Diff. Then change the last combo box to SCM you used.

Comment: I've read that one of the goals of this site is to store the answers right on the site, instead of pointing to external links. That way, if external links go down, the answer is still available.

Comment: still @nanda, so, from your helpful blog post, I have taken the liberty to cut/paste the following: This feature is called Quick Diff. It is turned on as default but the reference source is the last saved version. If your project use SVN (or CVS, Mercurial, Git as long as you use the Eclipse plugin for that SCM), you can change the Quick Diff behavior to compare the code on your machine with the latest code in the SCM. Go to Preferences and select General → Editors → Text Editors → Quick Diff. Then change the last combo box to SCM you used.

Comment: @martin: I put some quote to the answer